# Start matching specific whole words after the first four characters are typed

Tags: regex, regex-negation

The regex below matches the whole word `service`, `generic`, `computer` or `master`:

```
(?:^|(?<= ))(service|generic|computer|master)(?:(?= )|$)
```

I'd like it to match as soon as the first 4 characters are matched with the pattern.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use optional groups. And replace these `(?:^|(?<= ))` and `(?:(?= )|$)` alternations with `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)`

Comment: regex² : `"(?:^|(?<= ))(service|generic|computer|master)(?:(?= )|$)".replaceAll("(\\pL{4})\\pL+", "$1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested optional groups. Note you may also shortne the boundary patterns by replacing `(?:^|(?<= ))` and `(?:(?= )|$)` alternations with `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` lookarounds.

The pattern will look like

```
(?<!\S)(serv(?:i(?:ce?)?)?|gene(?:r(?:ic?)?)?|comp(?:u(?:t(?:er?)?)?)?|mast(?:er?)?)(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rEQ8oE/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - no non-whitespace immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
- `(` - alternation group start:

  - `serv(?:i(?:ce?)?)?` - `serv`, `servi`, `servic`, or `service`
  - `|` - or
  - `gene(?:r(?:ic?)?)?` - `gene`, `gener`, `generi` or `generic`
  - `|` - or
  - `comp(?:u(?:t(?:er?)?)?)?` - `comp`, `compu`, `comput`, `compute` or  `computer`
  - `|` - or
  - `mast(?:er?)?` - `mast`, `maste` or `master`
- `)` - end of the alternation group
- `(?!\S)` - no non-whitespace immediately to the right of the current location is allowed.